# Find the limit of $(n^3+2n^2)^{1/3}-n$

Tags: real-analysis

Find the limit of [sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEOtQ.png).I tried and get this
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{((n^3+2(n)^2)^{1/3}-n)\cdot((n^3+2 n ^2)^{1/3}+n)}{(2(n)^2+n^3)^{1/3}+n}
$$ I am getting limit 0 but this is wrong answer can you help?

Comment: Do you know wolframalpha.com ? Check it out. It is similar to latex code, you may look for a few examples there.

Answer (score 1):

$(1+x)^{1/3} = 1+ \frac x 3+o(x)$ as $x \to 0$. The given expression is  $n[(1+\frac2  {3n}) -1+o(1/n)]  \to \frac 2  3$

Comment: @Bernard Sorry?! This is entirely correct.

Comment: @ProfessorVector; *Now*, it is entirely correct. I'll remove my comment, since it is now irrelevant.

Comment: @Bernard I see. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just standard rearranging gives:

\begin{eqnarray*} (n^3+2n^2)^{1/3}-n
& = & (n^3+2n^2)^{1/3}-(n^3)^{\frac 13}\\
& \stackrel{a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)}{=} & \frac{n^3+2n^2 - n^3}{(n^3+2n^2)^{2/3} + (n^3+2n^2)^{1/3}n + n^2}\\
& = & \frac 2{(1+\frac 2n)^{2/3} + (1+\frac 2n)^{1/3} + 1}\\
& \stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} & \frac 23
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{n \to \infty}(n^3+2n^2)^{1/3}-n =\lim_{n \to \infty} n(1+2/n)^{1/3}-n$$
$$\implies L=\lim_{n \infty} n(1+2/(3n))-n=\lim_{n \to \infty} n+2/3-n=2/3$$
Her we have used binomial approximation that $(1+z)^k\to 1+kz$, if $|z|\ll 1.$

Answer (score 0):

> Find the $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(n^3+2n^2\right)^{1/3} ~-~ n$

You can regard $a_n = \left(n^3+2n^2\right)^{1/3} ~-~ n$ 
and then use the epsilon definition of the limit of a sequence to prove that the limit $~= (2/3).$

For all $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}, (n^3 + 2n^2) < (n + [2/3])^3 \implies$ 
$(n^3 + 2n^2)^{1/3} < (n + [2/3]) \implies$ 
$|~~(n^3 + 2n^2)^{1/3} - n - [2/3]~~| ~~=~~ (n +[2/3]) - (n^3 + 2n^2)^{1/3}.$

Further, you have the identity that 
$(A - B) = \frac{A^3 - B^3}{A^2 + AB + B^2} < \frac{A^3 - B^3}{A^2} ~:~$ when $A,B > 0.$

Therefore, the problem reduces to establishing that for any fixed $\epsilon > 0$, you can identify $N \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, 
$$\frac{(n + [2/3])^3 - (n^3 + 2n^2)}{(n + [2/3])^2} < \epsilon.$$

$$(n + [2/3])^3 - (n^3 + 2n^2) = [4/3]n + [8/27] < [4/3](n + [2/3]).$$

Therefore,

$$\frac{(n + [2/3])^3 - (n^3 + 2n^2)}{(n + [2/3])^2} < \frac{[4/3]}{n + [2/3]}.$$

Therefore, the problem reduces to demonstrating that for any $\epsilon > 0, N \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ can be found such that for all $n \geq N,$

$$\frac{[4/3]}{n + [2/3]} < \epsilon.$$

Simply choose $N \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that

$$\frac{[4/3]}{\epsilon} < N + [2/3].$$

Then you have that

$$n \geq N \implies (n + [2/3]) \geq (N + [2/3]) \implies
\frac{[4/3]}{n + [2/3]} < \epsilon.$$